# Output CSV file using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file, terraform-provider-openstack

I'm trying to use terraform variable data (CSV file) to create a resource group and the name of the resource group are added into the CSV file.

I'm currently experiencing the below error.

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
}

locals {
      resource_groupname = csvdecode(file("./test.csv"))
    }

    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Main" {
      count    = length(locals.resource_groupname)
      name     =  locals.resource_groupname[count.index].groupname   
      location = "North europe"
    }
```

Error Message

```
 Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on testvariable.tf line 10, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Customer11":
│   10:   count    = length(locals.groupname)
│
│ A managed resource "locals" "groupname" has not been declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on testvariable.tf line 11, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Customer11":
│   11:   name     = data.locals.groupname[count.index].groupname
│
│ A data resource "locals" "groupname" has not been declared in the root module.
╵
```

Updated Error Messgae

```
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on testtf.tf line 10, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Main":
│   10:       count    = length(locals.resource_groupname)
│
│ A managed resource "locals" "resource_groupname" has not been declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on testtf.tf line 11, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Main":
│   11:       name     =  locals.resource_groupname[count.index].groupname
│
│ A managed resource "locals" "resource_groupname" has not been declared in the root module.
```

Comment: What error? You haven't provided any.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for reaching out .....find the error image here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WgpIuV3_PWtX2vNUTSN9gc0jEz50oS25/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why your error does not match your code? The error says you have `name = data.locals.groupname[count.index].groupname` which is different than in your code.

Comment: I have made some changes and also go an updated error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be (assuming this time you posted correct code):

```
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Main" {
      count    = length(local.resource_groupname)
      name     =  local.resource_groupname[count.index].groupname   
      location = "North europe"
    }
```

Since `./test.csv` is not shown its difficult to speculate on its content and the use in your code.

Comment: this is the link to the content of the ./test.csv https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ituKDzaMVXnyynkjLBZRzMdWK9tnkL14/view?usp=sharing

Comment: tried the above code got this error 

 Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on testtf.tf line 11, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Main":
│   11:       name     =  local.resource_groupname[count.index].groupname
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is a number, known only after apply
│     │ local.resource_groupname is list of object with 3 elements
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "groupname".

Comment: @OgbeborAkpesiri It's a new issue, thus I would suggest making a new question with example CSV file. The original error posted in your question has be successfully addressed.

Comment: @OgbeborAkpesiri To accept you have to press "tick" button under up/down votes of the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your CSV file has headers like
name, location, ABC, XXY, CDF, your

then you use for_each as well here

```
locals {
      resource_groupname = csvdecode(file("./test.csv"))
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "Main" {
    for_each = { for inst in locals.resource_groupname) : inst.location=> inst 
    }
      
    name = each.value.name
    location =  each.value.location
}
```